# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing forwardslash(/)

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with the code below? I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /

```
$('#element').html($input.val().replace(/([^\\]*\\)*/,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to match here, but you need to close the opening parentheses and the bracket. So the RegExp should be:

```
/([^\]\)])/
```

The reason are `\]` and `\)` tokens. Those backslashes escape the characters, and thus, they are not treated as `)` and `]`. And the following doesn't make any sense:

```
/([^])/
```

as it will not match anything. The token `[^]` is to not match the characters in the bracket, but you don't have any.